# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{0}' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

i got an error when i was trying to excute the gridview row created event

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDetailedMes" runat="server" Width="800px"
                        ForeColor="black" GridLines="Horizontal" CellPadding="6" BackColor="white"
                        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowHeader="False" OnRowCreated="grdDetailedMes_rowcreated">                      

                    </asp:GridView>
```

and in .cs file

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ITS-BA-DC02\\MSSQL2008_SAND;Initial Catalog=TestDB_Chaitanya;User Id=sa;Password=01Explore");
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select MesDetails from InboxMesgDetails where InboxMesId='{0}'", cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            grdDetailedMes.DataSource = ds;
            grdDetailedMes.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }

protected void grdDetailedMes_rowcreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView headergrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow Headergridrow = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

            TableCell Headercell = new TableCell();
            Headercell.Text = "Company";

            Headercell.ColumnSpan = '2';
            Headergridrow.Cells.Add(Headercell);
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please, note that use `{}` (tool bar button) for putting your code parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

"select MesDetails from InboxMesgDetails where InboxMesId='{0}'"

Were you planning on doing a string.format on this?  You are currently not substituting that placeholder with anything.  Right now it is trying to use the literal {0}.  Additionally, the single quotes around that should not be necessary, as it appears your InboxMesId is an int

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass parameter for {0} for your query here :-

```
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select MesDetails from InboxMesgDetails where InboxMesId='{0}'", cnn);
```

In place of {0} , you should use '@Param' and should pass a valid parameter by using [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

You can do like-

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {

      String commandText="select MesDetails from InboxMesgDetails where InboxMesId=@ID";
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
      command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
      command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = InboxMesId;
      command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
      try
      {
          connection.Open();
          int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for substituting something in {0} ? 
If yes , Your code does not take care of this then.

SQL cannot convert { } to int.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful to you [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9.aspx)